# could not convert from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘arma::mat

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, initializer-list, armadillo

I just copy pasted from Armadillo matrix library [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_initialisation) to initialize a matrix object directly:

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    mat A = { {1, 3, 5},
              {2, 4, 6} };
    A.print();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the way I compiled it:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -larmadillo
```

But I cannot understand why I get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:22: error: could not convert ‘{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘arma::mat {aka arma::Mat<double>}’
            {2, 4, 6} };
                      ^
```

Comment: Likely the height of folly, but when I see the error with double when you're using int/long: what if you write `{ {1.0, 3.0, ...}`?

Comment: @JohnPerry, thanks for your attention. Using `double` numbers lead to the same problem. My numbers were originally double. In this website, I just copied from Armadillo documentation.

Comment: For this type of initialization you need at least Armadillo 5.200 and a compiler that supports the C++11 standard properly. It's know to work with gcc 5.1 and clang 3.5.  It may work with earlier versions of gcc, such as 4.9.

Comment: @hbrerkere my GCC is 4.9.2 but how can I check the version of my armadillo?

Comment: `std::cout << arma::arma_version::as_string() << std::endl;`

Comment: the output is `4.200.0 (Flintlock Swoop)` I had used `apt-get` to install armadillo.

Comment: Ubuntu has seriously outdated software. You can install a new version of Armadillo from the [download](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) page.

Comment: @hbrerkere the downloaded file includes a few source codes. Should I copy/paste `armadillo_bits` or I should run `cmake`?

Comment: First remove the previous version, then use the cmake based installation. See the README.txt file for more info.

Comment: @hbrerkere, Thanks a lot. The problem was with the version. I installed version `6.X` and the problem solved.